# Open Bootstrap DropDown that's within another TR>TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to Show and Hide Second TR on click of a DropDown Button "DropDown-AA" that's present in First TR.

I am actually looking for a code that's achieved in Bootstrap way. For Eg. `.trigger('click.bs.dropdown');`

```
<tr>
  <td class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown-AAA</a>
  </td>

  <td>&nbsp;</td>

  <td class="action-btns dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-link">DropDown-BBB</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item of BBB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item of BBB</a></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>

<!--I need to show and hide this below 'TR' when DropDown-AAA is clicked-->
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item of AAA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item of AAA</a></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: And what do you mean by archived? you mean achieve?

Comment: :) that was a typo @TolgaEvcimen. It's actually "achieved"

Answer (score 1):

Give your TR's id's. If you can get them with another approach its fine too.

```
<tr id="firstTR">
  <td class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown-AAA</a>
  </td>

  <td>&nbsp;</td>

  <td class="action-btns dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-link">DropDown-BBB</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item of BBB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item of BBB</a></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>

<!--I need to show and hide this below 'TR' when DropDown-AAA is clicked-->
<tr id="secondTR">
  <td colspan="3">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item of AAA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item of AAA</a></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And put this little script:

```
<script>
    $("#firstTR").on("click", function(){
        if( $("#secondTR").css("display") == "none" ){
            $("#secondTR").show();
        } else {
            $("#secondTR").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Think simple, I suggest :)